# C# wpf how to get the information of audio device

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I know C# can use wmi like:

```
using System.Management;

namespace TestDevice
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_SoundDevice");
                int count = 0;
                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    string name = queryObj["Name"].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(name);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

but in wpf, it cannot use ManagementObjectSearcher.

So, how to get the audio device in wpf?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a reference to `System.Management` to your project and you can use `ManagementObjectSearcher`.

Comment: To clarify, WPF is just a Graphical User Interface library. It does not limit the assemblies you can and cannot use.